# Rail Application Template - Causing Error on Server Start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I used a Rails Application Template on a quick app I was knocking up for someone.  It installed a new Ruby version through RVM, and everything was fine.  I've pushed it to Github, and it is being served via Heroku fine.

The problem comes when I tried to update it.  I am using the right Ruby version it installed, but when I start the server locally, I get an error, which I think relates to a Ruby version issue.

```
/Users/tomallen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse': (<unknown>): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 2 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse_stream'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:151:in `parse'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:127:in `load'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:115:in `database_configuration'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `block in on_load'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `each'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `on_load'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:74:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/tomallen/Documents/Sites/videoapp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/tomallen/Documents/Sites/videoapp/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /Users/tomallen/Documents/Sites/videoapp/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /Users/tomallen/Documents/Sites/videoapp/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Users/tomallen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Damn fool! Seems my database.yml was formatted incorrectly.  Just rewrote this and it works fine.

Comment: Hi, @user1756535, glad to hear you resolved your problem. In order to help future visitors, I would suggest posting an answer here that details the resolution to your problem, as suggested [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107405/169490), and accept your own answer.